The length of a curve determined by a curve in the tangent space starting from the origin.
Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold, $p$ is a point of $M$. Suppose $exp_p$ is defined on an open neighborhood $U$ of the origin, and let $v$ be a vector in $U$. By definition, the length of the curve $exp_p(tv), t\in[0,1]$ is just $|v|$. However, if I choose an arbitrary curve $\alpha(t)$ in $U$ joining the origin and $v$, what can I say about the length of $exp_p(\alpha(t))$. Is it necessary that the length of $exp_p(\alpha(t))$ is always larger than $|v|$?

I'm not so sure that your first fact is by definition. Here's how I see it: Let $v \in T_pM$ and let $\gamma_v(t)$ be the unique geodesic such that $\gamma_v(0) = p$ and $\gamma_v'(0) = v$. The definition of the exponential map tells us $\exp_p(tv) = \gamma_{tv}(1)$, and homogeneity of geodesics tells us that $\gamma_{tv}(1) = \gamma_v(t)$. Glue this together to conclude that $t \mapsto \exp_p(tv)$ is a geodesic whose length is
$$ \int_0^1 \| d_{tv}\exp_p(v)\| dt = \int_0^1 \|\dot{\gamma}_v(t)\| dt = \int_0^1 t \|v\| dt = \|v\|.$$
(If we had the Gauss lemma, then this is immediate)
As to your question, we can mimic the proof of Proposition 4.4.3 in https://www.math.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/%7Egcardoso/GeoRiem/nata_textb.pdf. Let $\alpha(t)$ be a curve on $U$ connecting the origin to $v$. Write $\alpha(t) = r(t) n(t)$, where $r : [0,1] \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ and $n : [0,1] \rightarrow T^1_pM$ are smooth. Letting
$$ \eta(t) := \exp_p(\alpha(t)) = \exp_p(r(t) n(t)),$$
we have
$$\dot{\eta}(t) = d_{\alpha(t)}\exp_p(\dot{r}(t)n(t) + r(t) \dot{n}(t)).$$
Now $\langle n(t), n(t) \rangle = 1$, so $\langle n(t), \dot{n}(t) \rangle = 0$. Thus
$$ \int_0^1 \|d_{\alpha(t)}\exp_p(\dot{\alpha}(t))\|dt = \int_0^1 ((\dot{r}(t))^2 + r(t)^2 \|d_{\alpha(t)}exp_p(\dot{n}(t))\|^2)^{1/2}dt \ (by \ Gauss's \ lemma) \\\geq \int_0^1 \dot{r}(t)dt = r(1) - r(0).$$
By construction, $r(0) = 0$ (since we need $\alpha(0) = 0$), and $r(1) = \|v\|$.

Thanks about your answer. It seems that I made a silly mistake when reading Do Carmo's hint in Exercise 1 of Chapter 10 in his book Riemannian Geometry. It is a ball $B$ of some radius in the manifold but not a ball of some radius in the tangent space. Finding out this mistake, I realized that the exercise did not assume what I have asked here. Therefore I delete the second paragraph in my question. Now that this is a question I do not know whether this is true or not. I will try to read that pdf that you link here.

I think this is an excellent answer applying Gauss's lemma. And I think there is a minor mistake, $|d_{\alpha(t)}exp_p(\dot{n}(t))|$ is not necessarily $|\dot{n}(t)|$, but this does not change the conclusion. Thanks about your answer.

Thanks for catching that!
